# Connecting Xampp to my android device

Tags: php, android, apache, xampp

I created a login android app which validates the username and password using php. I have used android studio,xampp and phpmyadmin for this.

First i tested this app in my genymotion using the ip address **10.0.3.2(http://10.0.3.2/client/login.php)** and it worked fine.

Later, I connected my android device (lenovo A6000 plus) and changed the IP address to **192.168.x.x:80 (http://192.168.x.x:80/client/login.php)** in my code and executed my app. But now the connection is not made and app doesn't work as desired.

I changed the config in the file http-xampp-config to **"Allow from all"**.But the problem persists.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: did you shutdown the firewall ?

Comment: What error do you get as a server responce?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
change your port address 10.0.3.2 to 10.0.2.2

http://10.0.2.2/client/login.php

Comment: That IP address is used for emulators. The OP states his emulator works fine. For testing on a physical device, he is using a 192.168.x.x private IP address which doesn't work. Your suggestion won't be useful here.

Comment: I don't think your firewall allowed to access internal web service through Android App.So make sure shutdown the firewall and check the connectivity.